# Alert View and Action sheets in ios

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am a beginner in I-phone OS.I have seen action sheets and alert views.I seems like they both functions like same. May i know the exact differences between them.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An alert gives people important information that affects their use of the app (or the device).**

**An action sheet displays a set of choices related to a task the user initiates.**

Please refer apple's [MobileHIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) document for detailed description.

> **UIAlertView Guidelines**
>
> The infrequency with which alerts appear helps users take them
>   seriously. Be sure to minimize the number of alerts your app displays
>   and ensure that each one offers critical information and useful
>   choices.
>
> Avoid creating unnecessary alerts.
>
> In general, alerts are unnecessary if they:
>
> ```
> Merely increase the visibility of some information, especially information that is related to the standard functioning of your app.
>
> Instead, you should design an eye-catching way to display the information that harmonizes with your app’s style.
>
> Update users on tasks that are progressing normally.
>
> Instead, consider using a progress view or an activity indicator to provide progress-related feedback to users (these methods of
> ```
>
> feedback are described in “Progress View” and “Activity Indicator”).
>
> ```
> Ask for confirmation of user-initiated actions.
>
> To get confirmation for an action the user initiated, even a potentially risky action such as deleting a contact, you should use an
> ```
>
> action sheet.
>
> ```
> Inform users of errors or problems about which they can do nothing.
>
> Although it might be necessary to use an alert to tell users about a critical problem they can’t fix, it’s better to integrate such
> ```
>
> information into the UI, if possible. For example, instead of telling
>   users every time a server connection fails, display the time of the
>   last successful connection.
>
> **UIActionSheet Guidelines**
>
> Use an action sheet to:
>
> ```
> Provide alternate ways a task can be completed. An action sheet allows you to provide a range of choices that make sense in the
> ```
>
> context of the current task, without giving these choices a permanent
>   place in the user interface.
>
> ```
> Get confirmation before completing a potentially dangerous task. An action sheet prompts users to think about the potentially dangerous
> ```
>
> effects of the step they’re about to take and gives them some
>   alternatives. This type of communication is particularly important on
>   iOS-based devices because sometimes users tap controls without meaning
>   to.
>
> On iPhone, coordinate the action sheet background appearance with the
>   navigation bars and toolbars. Use the translucent black background if
>   your app uses black navigation bars and toolbars. Use the default blue
>   background if your navigation bars and toolbars are the default blue
>   color.
>
> All action sheets in your iPhone app should have the same background
>   color.
>
> On iPhone, include a Cancel button so that users can easily and safely
>   abandon the task. Place the Cancel button at the bottom of the action
>   sheet to encourage users to read through all the alternatives before
>   making a choice. By default, the appearance of the Cancel button
>   coordinates with the background of the action sheet.
>
> On iPad, choose whether to display an action sheet with animation or
>   without animation.
>
> ```
> Display an action sheet without animation to provide alternatives related to a task that the user initiates from outside a popover.
> ```
>
> Without animation, an action sheet and its popover appear
>   simultaneously. When you display an action sheet this way, the
>   popover’s arrow points to the control or area the user tapped to
>   initiate the task.
>
> ```
> Do not include a Cancel button when the action sheet is displayed without animation, because people can tap outside the popover to
> ```
>
> dismiss the action sheet without selecting one of the other
>   alternatives.
>
> ```
> Display an action sheet with animation to provide alternatives related to a task that the user initiates from within an open popover.
> ```
>
> With animation, an action sheet slides up over an open popover’s
>   content.
>
> ```
> An animated action sheet should include a Cancel button, because people need to be able to dismiss the action sheet without closing the
> ```
>
> popover.

Comment: Please post comments when downvoting, so that I can find the fault and improve myself :)

Answer (score 3):

As the name indicates. An AlertView is used primarily to ALERT the user of something.. Like 'We have downloaded a new message for you!'.

An ActionSheet is used used to let the user specify an ACTION. Like 'What would you like to do? Edit, Delete, Cancel'

So the first is for alerting the user and the other is asking for an action.

Comment: You can use them interchangeably. I tend to use whichever one looks aesthetically better for the situation, but Ron's answer is essentially correct.